# How does andThen() work in RXJava2?

Tags: rx-java2

Trying to learn RXJava2's `Completable.andThen()`.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    showTime()
        .andThen(showTime())
        .subscribe()
}

private fun showTime(): Completable =
    Completable.create {
        println(System.currentTimeMillis())
    }
```

I am expecting the above code to print time twice, but it's only doing it once. What is it I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`andThen` is just shortcut for `concatWith` operator. Your second `showTime` is never subcribed to as you never call `onComplete` - you have a `CompletableEmitter` Object inside the lambda.

Your method should be:

```
private fun showTime(): Completable =  
    Completable.create {
        println(System.currentTimeMillis())
        it.onComplete()
    }
```